# newtxsf: Font shape undefined

Tags: fonts

In TeX-Live 2014, I installed `newtxsf.sty` using the TeX-Live manager tool. I then tried the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault,scaled=.85]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxsf}

\begin{document}

$abcdef\cdot xyz\leq \alpha\beta\gamma\cdot\varphi\varepsilon\omega$

$x^2(x+1)=x^3+x^2>1$ for every $x\in\mathbb{N}$

\[ \int\limits_a^b x^2 \mathrm{d}x \]

\end{document}
```

Preamble is intentionally left as shown in `texdoc newtxsf`. However, compiling the document with `pdflatex` or `latex` yields

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/ntxsym/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `U/ntxexa/m/n' instead on input line 11.
```

I do not quite understand why this happens and thus have no ideal on how I could solve the problem.

As a followup to Ulrike's comment:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.2.14)  18 SEP 2016 19:57
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input cleanfonttest.tex
(./cleanfonttest.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fira/FiraSans.sty
Package: FiraSans 2014/11/19 (Bob Tennent and autoinst) Style file for Fira San
s fonts.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count87
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 71.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 266.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 281.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 282.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 283.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 284.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 285.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 286.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 287.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 288.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 289.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 290.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 291.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 292.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 293.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 294.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 295.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 296.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 297.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 298.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 299.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 300.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 301.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 302.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 303.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 304.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 305.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 306.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 307.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 308.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 309.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 310.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 311.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 312.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 313.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 314.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 315.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 316.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 317.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 318.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 319.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 320.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 321.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 322.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 323.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 324.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 325.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 326.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 327.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 328.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 329.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 330.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 331.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 332.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 333.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 335.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 336.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 337.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 338.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 339.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 340.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mweights/mweights.sty
Package: mweights 2013/07/21 (Bob Tennent) Support package for multiple-weight 
font packages. 
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bfseries on input line 22.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mdseries on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 36.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 53.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 70.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty
Package: fontaxes 2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen103
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count88
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count89
\leftroot@=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count91
\DOTSCASE@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count93
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count94
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count95
\dspbrk@lvl=\count96
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count97
\column@=\count98
\maxfields@=\count99
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2009/07/02 v2.20.1
\thm@style=\toks21
\thm@bodyfont=\toks22
\thm@headfont=\toks23
\thm@notefont=\toks24
\thm@headpunct=\toks25
\thm@preskip=\skip46
\thm@postskip=\skip47
\thm@headsep=\skip48
\dth@everypar=\toks26
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtxsf/newtxsf.sty
Package: newtxsf 2015/04/07 v1.02

`newtxsf' v1.02, 2015/04/07 Math macros based on STIX sans serif and txfonts (m
sharpe) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex)
\tx@Isdigit=\count100
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `T1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/n on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `T1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/n on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/n --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/b/n on input li
ne 44.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathsf on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/n on input line 50.

LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 51.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/it on input line 51.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/it on input line 51
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathtt on input line 52.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> T1/cmtt/m/n on input line 52.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> T1/cmtt/m/n on input line 52.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 54.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/b/n on input line 54.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/b/n on input line 54.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/it --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/b/it on input 
line 55.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/n --> T1/FiraSans-OsF/b/n on input li
ne 56.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/cmtt/m/n --> T1/cmtt/b/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 62.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/ntxsfmi/m/it on input line 62.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/ntxsfmi/m/it on input line 62.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/ntxsfmi/m/it --> OML/ntxsfmi/b/it on input line 63.

\symlettersA=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lettersA' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/ntxsfmia/m/it --> U/ntxsfmia/b/it on input line 70.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 78.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/ntxsy/m/n on input line 78.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/ntxsy/m/n on input line 78.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/ntxsy/m/n --> OMS/ntxsy/b/n on input line 79.
\symAMSm=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/ntxsym/m/n --> U/ntxsym/b/n on input line 99.
\symsymbolsC=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbolsC' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/ntxsyc/m/n --> U/ntxsyc/b/n on input line 121.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 134.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `LMX' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 1
34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> LMX/ntxexx/m/n on input line 134.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `LMX' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 134
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> LMX/ntxexx/m/n on input line 134.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  LMX/ntxexx/m/n --> LMX/ntxexx/b/n on input line 135.
\symlargesymbolsTXA=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbolsTXA' in version `bold'

(Font)                  U/ntxexa/m/n --> U/ntxexa/b/n on input line 146.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lfloor on input line 229.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rfloor on input line 230.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lceil on input line 231.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rceil on input line 232.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lbrace on input line 233.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rbrace on input line 234.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \langle on input line 235.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rangle on input line 237.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mid on input line 239.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \arrowvert on input line 241.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \vert on input line 242.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Arrowvert on input line 244.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Vert on input line 245.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \updownarrow on input line 247.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Updownarrow on input line 248.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \m@thbbch@rA on input line 1216.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \not on input line 1467.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsquare on input line 1488.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \openbox on input line 1490.
)
No file cleanfonttest.aux.
\openout1 = `cleanfonttest.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/ntxsfmi/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+ntxsfmi on input line 
9.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtxsf/omlntxsfmi.fd
File: omlntxsfmi.fd 2014/11/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/ntxsfmi
.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/ntxsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+ntxsy on input line 9.


(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/omsntxsy.fd
File: omsntxsy.fd 2012/11/14 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OMS/ntxsy.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/ntxexa/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxexa on input line 9.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxexa.fd
File: untxexa.fd 2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxexa.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 9.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LMX/ntxexx/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+FiraSans-OsF on input l
ine 9.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fira/T1FiraSans-OsF.fd
File: T1FiraSans-OsF.fd 2014/11/19 (autoinst) Font definitions for T1/FiraSans-
OsF.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.50006pt on input line 9.
\c@mv@tabular=\count101
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count102
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.20503pt on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/FiraSans-OsF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 4.67503pt on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxsfmia on input line 1
1.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtxsf/untxsfmia.fd
File: untxsfmia.fd 2014/11/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsfmia.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxsym on input line 11.

LaTeX Font Info:    No file Untxsym.fd. on input line 11.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/ntxsym/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `U/ntxexa/m/n' instead on input line 11.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxsyc on input line 11.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxsyc.fd
File: untxsyc.fd 2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyc.
) [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./clea
nfonttest.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Show your log-file.

Comment: How did you use `tlmgr` with TeX Live 2014? How did you install the TeX Live distribution exactly?

Comment: `sudo tlmgr install newtxsf` and before that, I set the repository to `ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2014/tlnet-final`. I do not actually remember how I installed the distribution, it was a while ago. I downloaded the installation package and everything went well, as always :) I have never had any problem, be it with the distribution or with adding packages at a later moment.

Comment: Install `newtx`.

Comment: `tlmgr info newtx` [...] `installed: Yes`

Comment: You are missing the fd-file ` LaTeX Font Info:    No file Untxsym.fd. on input line 11.`. On my tl 2014 system it is in texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxsym.fd. Perhaps you should try to run tlmgr update --all.

Comment: Danke Ulrike :) I noticed the missing file, but had no explanation on why that happened. I chose the somehow lazier way by doing `tlmgr update newtx` (thanks to cfr for pointing out the link to that package, too). Problem solved. Would either of you mind posting an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem has been solved by comments.